# Copy cell info on account of cell matching specific te

Tags: google-sheets

Edited as response to comment:
I had to copy data into a new sheet, which is why it doesnt entirely match your answer.

Here is where Im at now: attached screendump is new.
[image: This is from the shared spreadsheet]

Hope you can help with this one, usually get on OK with a function or two, but this wont work for me :-)

I need a code in N24 that currently says #ERROR! to do the following:
If G24 = AAA AND H24:L24 contains the text DEL 1, it should show E24 (3).

The result should be, under LIST, there should be a 3, because DEL 1 is selected in one of the cells.
It should check the entire H-L columns, but only list the cell-info from the TEXT-column, if that same line also has AAA in STATUS.

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`=if((if(G24="AAA",1,0))+(iferror(match("DEL1",H24:L24,0),0))>1,E24,"")`

Comment: Much appreciated - but it just gives a "parse error"?

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: What sheet/cell has the parse error?

Comment: Works just fine. Of course, you need to replace "AAA" with OPTION1", and "DEL1" with "DEL 1"

Comment: Hmm, just pressed the link, and seems my saves/changes doesnt show on shared file... weird

Comment: Ah, it linked to the ODS, but every time I made change in Google Sheets, it save a new sheet... here is a shareable link that should go to the correct file - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yOapcmzWaaNd50Z86Wpszfu5tKJXhlI2SGm-51kA6Hg

Comment: Your "MATCH" range: `PAGE1!D5:H6`. It should be: `PAGE1!D5:H5`

Comment: Just tried that - but still dont get a value. I would also prefer that it looked through the entire columns D-H so I can use the same code in all of the list on PAGE2 (next to DEL1-DEL5). This is why it should be dependent of matching OPTION1 - so when that is switched to OPTION2, it removes the value of page 2

Comment: Your spreadsheet hasn't been updated; there is not error showing. "This is why it should be dependent of matching OPTION1 - so when that is switched to OPTION2, it removes the value of page 2" - you will find that this is exactly what it DOES do. Please update your spreadsheet!

Comment: Ah, I found the error - in the MATCH I changed the "DEL 1" to refer to a cell (H5) but forgot to remove the "" so it was looking for text H5 instead of the cell. It works - brilliant - very much appreciated

Comment: Your "MATCH" search key: `H5`. It should be: `DEL 1`

Comment: I used H5 instead of "DEL 1" so I can copy to code to the next row on PAGE2!G6 so that it searches for "DEL 2" from PAGE2!H6 instead. But it returns 222 from PAGE1!A6, even when PAGE1!C6 is OPTION2. And would it be possible to change the cells it searches (D5:H5) to the entire D:H columns? Tried removing the numbers, but then dont get a return

Comment: You are changing to question, and you are also making flawed assumptions about how "MATCH" will work as it is copied down a row. Could we please just make sure that the answer/formula provides a satisfactory outcome to the question first asked..

Comment: I did put in original question "It should check the entire H-L columns" - but it might have gotten lost in some of my replies. But the formula you provided works - but I would like to go a bit further. I can make a new question if that is more correct for this forum.

Comment: "I need a code in N24 that currently says #ERROR! to do the following: If G24 = AAA AND H24:L24 contains the text DEL 1, it should show E24 (3)." You just take the formula in Cell N24 and copy it down Column N as many rows as you want. I suggest that you ask a new question since this will ensure the largest possible audience for the problem you wish to raise. May I suggest that you share (for edit, not view) a copy of your spreadsheet, and that this includes an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Ill put up a new question - here is a link to the file that is working with the formula you provided - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yOapcmzWaaNd50Z86Wpszfu5tKJXhlI2SGm-51kA6Hg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Apologies. Hadn't noticed that "H5" was linking to a variable.